# First eigenvalue of Laplacian and Poincaré inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Any idea on how to solve: $\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 d^n x=\lambda_1\int_{\Omega}u^2 d^n x$, with $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\lambda_1$ the first eigenvalue of the negative Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary conditions on $\Omega$ - I am suspecting $u$ is the eigenfunction corresponding to $\lambda_1$, but I am looking for a rigorous proof.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? That equality is clearly true if $u$ is the first eigenfunction - just integrate by parts. Are you asking whether this equality means $u$ *must* be the first eigenfunction?

Comment: Yes. I was wondering how to from the equality to showing that u is the first eigenfunction.

Comment: it's true. I don't have time to write up an answer, but look for the variational characterization of Laplace eigenvalues. The quantity $\int |\nabla u|^2 / \int u^2$ (the Rayleigh quotient) is minimized at (and only at) the first eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

First solution:

Let $S=\{u\in H_0^1(\Omega):\ J(u)=1\}$ where $J:H_0^1(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$J(u)=\int_\Omega |u|^2=\|u\|_2^2$$ Define $I:S\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$I(u)=\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2=\|u\|_{1,2}^2$$

i - $\lambda_1=\min_{u\in S} I(u)$

ii - If $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ satisfies $I(u)=\lambda _1$ then, $u$ is a eigenfunction associated with $\lambda_1$.

To prove ii, note that the tangent plane of $S$ in $u$ is given by $S^\perp_u=\{v\in S:\ \int_\Omega uv=0\}$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small number and condider the function $F:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times S^\perp_u\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by  $$F(t,v)=\int_\Omega\left|\nabla \left(\frac{u+tv}{\|u+tv\|_2}\right)\right|^2$$

Note that $\frac{u+tv}{\|u+tv\|_2}$ is a parametrization of $S$ in a neighbourhood of $u$. For each fixed $v\in S^{\perp}_u$ we have that $t=0$ is a minimum for the function $F(t,v)$. If you calculate the derivative, you will find that $$\frac{dF(0,v)}{dt}=\int_\Omega \nabla u\nabla v-\lambda_1\int_\Omega uv=0$$

Now you can conclude.

Second solution:

This answer assumes that the eigenvalues of the operator $-\Delta$ were characterized by means of Fredholm alternative and also that $\lambda_1$ is characterized by i. In particular, we have a spectral decomposition of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and the multiplicity of the eigenvalues are finite.

Assume that $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ satisfies $\|u\|_{1,2}^2=\lambda_1$ and $\|u\|_2=1$. Write  $$u=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (u,\varphi_i)\varphi_i$$

where $\varphi_i$ are the eigenfunctions associated with $\lambda_i$ (remember that it is a orthogonal decomposition) and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes inner product in $H_0^1(\Omega)$. Note that $$\lambda_1=\|u\|_{1,2}^2=(u,u)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i(u,\varphi_i)^2\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, remember that $\|u\|_2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (u,\varphi_i)^2$, therefore $$\lambda_1= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_1(u,\varphi_i)^2\tag{2}$$

We combine $(2)$ and $(3)$ to conclude that

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\lambda_i-\lambda_1)(u,\varphi_i)^2=0$$

which implies that $\lambda_i=0$ for $\lambda_i>\lambda_1$. Because $\lambda_1$ has finite multiplicity, we conclude that $u=\sum_{i=1}^m (u,\varphi_i)\varphi_i$, where each $\varphi_i$ with $i=1,...,m$ is an eigenfunction associated with $\lambda_1$, hence $$-\Delta u=-\Delta \left(\sum_{i=1}^m (u,\varphi_i)\varphi_i\right)=-\sum_{i=1}^m (u,\varphi_i)\Delta \varphi_i=\lambda_1 u$$

Comment: I understand the proof, but IMHO, you are skipping a few steps, which makes it harder to understand, and there are a couple of typos :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Frank. With respect to the gaps, they are intentional: I will not give you an full answer, because I want you to think about it. With respect to the typos, they are unintentional, so feel free to correct them. However, if there is some point where you are completely lost, you can leave a comment here and I will try to help you.

Comment: Tomas - to be clear, I can fill in all the gaps, no worries. No, I think the proofs are correct, it's just that to the uninitiated in FA, it's steep. For example, in the definition of  $||||_{1,2}$, I assume is the definition in $W^{1,2}$, which includes $u^2$, but $u^2$ drops because $u$ is in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. But no problem, I think I totally get it.